# Use NSPredicate to retrieve information in core data from relationship

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

Hello i have this Core data:

[image]

then i do this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                           entityForName:@"MyDate"  inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
```

now i want use the NSPredicate to take only the MyDate with the Task for the taskes relationship that have isView = NO and the taskDate <= today, and that the count of all Task for each MyDate is > 0...there is a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough points to comment, so jumping off of Nikita's answer, all you need to do is the following:

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY taskes.isView = NO AND ANY taskes.taskDate <= %@", todayDate];`

One way you can get today's date (there might be better ways):

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSDate *todayDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

Comment: And will this predicate select the Taskes that **both** are isView = NO AND date< today?Or it will just return the dates,that has taskes,which satisfies just one of this conditions?I just 've never used ANY and i'm interested

Answer (score 0):

Use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskes.@count>0 AND (ANY (taskes.isView = NO AND taskes.taskDate<%@)",today]; "`
Not sure,but maybe it would work